# send array of bytes to System.Media.SoundPlayer in c#

Tags: c#, byte, wav, soundplayer

I want send string byte to speaker something like this:

```
byte[] bt = {12,32,43,74,23,53,24,54,234,253,153};// example array
var ms = new MemoryStream(bt);
var sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer();
sound.Stream = ms;
sound.Play();
```

but I get this exception:
[my problem pic http://8pic.ir/images/g699b52xe5ap9s8yf0pz.jpg](http://8pic.ir/images/g699b52xe5ap9s8yf0pz.jpg)

Comment: What the speaker is supposed to do with that *random* series of bytes ? You need to *form* a valid WAV stream.

Comment: The SoundPlayer class is expecting a .wav file, not a random stream of bytes. Your byte stream does not have a header that corresponds to a .wav file, hence the error. So you've shown us what you've tried, can you tell us a bit more about exactly what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: butnext i want to get byte string from microphone

Comment: i want to save bytes that can to be made by analog wave
and send them by TCP/IP and play by another speaker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some library for reading data from microphone or playing it to speakers.
I worked successfuly with:
**NAudio - http://naudio.codeplex.com/**

I would not recommend building a WAV file yourself, it may be too much effort for this. 
Note that this library (and probably some others, **Bass** - http://www.un4seen.com is also widely used) also have built in functionality for saving and reading WAV files.

Comment: so you mean i get wave file from mic and send this wave file with TCP/IP and on other computer send to it s speaker?
if i can discard heaer and footer wawe file it dot waste width band

Comment: If you do not need to save the data, just send it and play - you can easily do it by sending packets over the network, and for this I used NAudio directly. I am not sure how easy it is to play these with Media.SoundPlayer - but playing them with NAUdio is not hard

Comment: dear shade 
i found http://www.alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx you can consider this.it is very nice example

Answer (score 1):

The first bytes of a WAV stream contain info about length, etc.
You have to send this "WAV-Header" as well in the first few bytes.

See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/RIFF_WAVE

As you'll see its perfectly possible to compose these few bytes in the header and send them before your raw audio data,

Comment: you mean i have to attach wav-header first my byte string if i want t send them to speaker????

Comment: Yes, the first couple of bytes are the RIFF-WAV Header, see the link

Comment: The header includes length of raw data as well.

Answer (score 0):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is best app to play that functionality. use sample app provided.It may help.

Comment: alvas.net/alvas.audio,articles.aspx this is very nice for wave file example.